# viewDidAppear called after applicationDidEnterBackground?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-lifecycle

As far as I know nothing can be called after `applicationDidEnterBackground` returns since after that the app gets suspended. My app is designed in such a way - it start with the initial controller which loads some data from the server and once it is loaded it segues to another controller. I set a break point to `viewWill/DidAppear` of my second vc and another breakpoint to
`applicationDidEnterBackground` in AppDelegate. The I start the app and immediately minimised it. To my big surprise `applicationDidEnterBackground` was not the last breakpoint that I was able to catch! Sometimes I was catching them in this order `SecondVC.viewWillAppear`  -> `applicationDidEnterBackground`  -> `SecondVC.viewDidAppear`  and sometimes in this `applicationDidEnterBackground`  -> `SecondVC.viewWillAppear`  -> `SecondVC.viewDidAppear` 
! How is this possible ? The only adequate explanation that I can figure out is that when the app is attached to debugger lifecycle works slightly different but I'm not sure that this is the reason. So, can somebody explain why this happens? Thank you!

Comment: You should have to give codes which you have tried regarding your statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`applicationDidEnterBackground:` is not the last routine that is executed by the app process before it gets suspended.

According to the [description](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622997-applicationdidenterbackground?language=objc) of this method, your app process is not suspended for about the next 5 (five) seconds after this method is called, and keeps running normally.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I marked this one as excepted